# How to obtain text from a textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

***UPDATE***
Ok, after trying ".value" for god knows x amount of time again, it some how worked.....  Problem solved. Thanks a lot for those who has responded.
***UPDATE***

How can I obtain the text(strings) from my form on my HTML page with Javascript?

I just want to take whatever was inputted into the text box and write into my XML file.
For example, if I type "HELLO" into the text box, I want "HELLO" written in the XML file.

I have tried both ".value" and ".text", they don't work. Also tried ".textcontent", no good too. I'm thinking that I need to use a different code.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:
http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/5677/sdfsdfsdfs.jpg

Here are the files if you want to mess with them personally:
http://www.mediafire.com/?e29t6ipatsqun70

Here's my HTML file:

```
    <html>
    <!--onSubmit="SaveXML(person);"-->
    <head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_LABs.css" />
    </head>

    <body> 
    <script type="text/javaScript"  src="LoginJS.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javaScript"  src="writeXML.js"> </script>

    <div class="form">
    <form id="Registration" name="reg" action="" method="get" onSubmit="initialize_array()">

    Username:<input type="text" name="Usrname"  id="Usrname" maxlength="10"/> <br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="Pswd" id="Pswd" maxlength="20"/> <br/>

    <hr>

    PersonID:<input type="text" name="PersonID" id="PersonID"/> <br>

    <hr>

    First Name:<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"/> <br>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName"/>

    <hr>

    DOB:<input type="text" name="DOB" id="DOB"/> <br>

    <hr>

    Gender:<input type="text" name="Gender" id="Gender"/> <br>

    <hr>

    Title:<input type="text" name="Title" id="Title"/> <br>

    <hr>

    <!--Secret Question:<br>
    <select name="secret?">
    </select> <br>

    Answer:<input type="text" name="answer" /> <br> <br>-->

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Here's my Javascript file:

```
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var FILENAME = 'G:\\CST2309 - Web Programming 1\\Copy of Take Home Exam - Copy\\PersonXML2.xml';

    function SaveXML(UserData) 
    {   
        var usrn = document.getElementById("Username").text;
        var pswd = document.getElementById("Pswd").text;
    var pid = document.getElementById("PersonID").text;
        var fname = document.getElementById("FirstName").text;     //This is where I'm having trouble with
    var lname = document.getElementById("LastName").text;
        var gender = document.getElementById("Gender").text;
    var dob = document.getElementById("DOB").text;
        var title = document.getElementById("Title").text;

        var file = fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);
        file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n');
        file.WriteLine('<PersonInfo>\n');

        for (countr = 0; countr < UserData.length; countr++) {
            file.Write('    <Person ');
            file.Write('Usrname="' + UserData[countr][0] + '" ');
            file.Write('Pswd="' + UserData[countr][1] + '" ');
    file.Write('PersonID="' + UserData[countr][2] + '" ');
            file.Write('FirstName="' + UserData[countr][3] + '" ');
            file.Write('LastName="' + UserData[countr][4] + '" ');
            file.Write('Gender="' + UserData[countr][5] + '" ');
            file.Write('DOB="' + UserData[countr][6] + '" ');
            file.Write('Title="' + UserData[countr][7] + '"');
            file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');
        } // end for countr

        file.Write('    <Person ');
        file.Write('Usrname="' + usrn + '" ');
        file.Write('Pswd="' + pswd + '" ');
    file.Write('PersonID="' + pid + '" ');
        file.Write('FirstName="' + fname + '" ');
        file.Write('LastName="' + lname + '" ');
        file.Write('Gender="' + gender + '" ');
        file.Write('DOB="' + dob + '" ');
        file.Write('Title="' + title + '" ');
        file.WriteLine('></Person>\n');  

        file.WriteLine('</PersonInfo>\n');
        file.Close();

    } // end SaveXML function --------------------

    function LoadXML(xmlFile) 
    {
        xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
        return xmlDoc.documentElement;
    } //end function LoadXML()

    function initialize_array() 
    {
        var person = new Array();
        var noFile = true;
        var xmlObj;
        if (fso.FileExists(FILENAME)) 
        {
            xmlObj = LoadXML(FILENAME);
            noFile = false;
            } // if
        else 
        {
            xmlObj = LoadXML("PersonXML.xml");
            //alert("local" + xmlObj);
            } // end if

        var usrCount = 0;
        while (usrCount < xmlObj.childNodes.length) 
        {
            var tmpUsrs = new Array(xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Usrname"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Pswd"),
                        xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("PersonID"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("FirstName"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("LastName"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Gender"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("DOB"),
                                    xmlObj.childNodes(usrCount).getAttribute("Title"));
            person.push(tmpUsrs);
            usrCount++;
             }   //end while
        if (noFile == false)
            fso.DeleteFile(FILENAME);
        SaveXML(person);
    }   // end function initialize_array()
```

Comment: You know this will only work in IE? And you know you're creating a global variable `countr` at the beginning of that `for` loop?

Comment: BTW, you get `null` because you ask for `document.getElementById("Username")` while the `id` actually reads `Usrname`. And AFAIK you should really use `.value`, not `.text`. And you should just use `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Comment: It's fine, this is not for the real world, just something I'm doing. Well, I was trying different things because .value was not working. The array doesn't have any issues. Anyway, is it possible that you can show me an example of a code that would make it work?

Comment: Yes, every single one of your references to ".text" should be ".value".

Comment: I'm just leaving it as .text because I was too lazy to change it when I posted. But yeah, .value and .text does work. Both don't seem to grab the string from the text box.


Anyway, for example, if I enter "hello" into the text box, "hello" doesn't come up on my XML file. Only "[object]" comes up.

Comment: Look, @MNX1024, ".value" is the correct attribute to access, and ".text" is incorrect. That it happens to work is irrelevant - there's a right way and a wrong way to do things.

Comment: @Pointy, When I created this post, I just left the ".text" there because changing it on this post serves no purpose what so ever. I have already stated that I've used both ".value" and ".text", both does not work "at all" for what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is take the input on the text box and put it in its respective place in the XML file. What I'm asking for is, the correct code use to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById("UsrName").value` to get tha value of a field in your form. Due to you use id for every field, so there is no problem using this code.

Something around: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1143011&page=1

Comment: Yeah, that was my fault there, didn't realize that there's a typo. The problem is that the code is not grabbing the text that I enter and place it in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of it working. I changed some functionality around just to show that the function was seeing the values correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/73gbH/1

But like everyone said change `.text` to `.value`